# Save an html page + change all links to point to the right place

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, screen-scraping

You probably know that IE has this thing where you can save a web page, and it will automatically download the html file and all he image/css/js files that the html file uses.

Now there is one problem with this- the links in the html file are not changed. 
So if I download the html page of example.com, which has an < a href=/hi.html> the page that I downloaded with IE will have a link to C:\Documents and Settings...(path to the folder that the html file is in).

Is there a python library that will download an html page for me, with all the contents of it (images/js/css) too?
If yes, is there a library that will also change the links for me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just an idea.. you could do a simple Find and Replace in the HTML file.

Comment: Are you sure that is says <a href="c:\Documents and Settings..."> in the HTML file?  Or, does it say <a href="/hi.html"> and your browser inserts the "file://" business because the page is local.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're mentioning IE specifically, I'm not sure if this is gonna be of any use to you, but on linux the easiest way to completely mirror a website is with the wget command.

```
wget --mirror --convert-links -w 1 http://www.example.com
```

Run man wget if you need more options.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool to save web pages into a single standalone html file, and the links are pointed to the same place as it should be.

https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html